# SQL: Filter records based on record creation date and other criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am struggling to find a better solution to pick unique records from my user call data table. 
My table structure is as follows:

```
SELECT [MarketName],
       [WebsiteName] ,
       [ID] ,
       [UserID],
       [CreationDate],
       [CallDuration],
       [FromPhone] ,
       [ToPhone],
       [IsAnswered],
       [Source]
FROM [dbo].[UserCallData]
```

There are multiple entries in this table with different and same ID's. I wanted to check if [FromPhone] and [ToPhone] exists multiple times within last 3 months, if yes, I wanted to pick the first record with all columns based on [CreationDate], count the number of occurrences as TotalCallCount and sum the totalCallDuration as a single record. If [FromPhone] and [ToPhone] does not occur multiple times, I wanted to pick all columns as such. I have been able to put up partial query like below. But this doesn't return all columns without including in group by clause and also it doesn't satisfy my entire criteria. Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

```
select  [FromPhone], 
        MIN([CreationDate]),
        [ToPhone], 
        marketname, 
        count(*) as TotalCallCount , 
        sum(CallDuration) as TotalCallDuration 
from [dbo].[UserCallData]
where  [CreationDate] >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
group by  [FromPhone],[ToPhone], marketname 
having count([FromPhone]) > 1 and count([ToPhone]) >1
```

Comment: We're clearly having problems understanding your request. Could you give us: (a) the "create table" script for the UserCallData table, (b) some sample data (anonymised if that's necessary), and (c) the expected output when using that sample data as the input. The data should include rows which illustrate how you want all cases to be handled (so, minimally, some within the last three months, some not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use ROW_NUMBER()

```
;with cte as
(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FromPhone, ToPhone ORDER BY CreationDate) as RN
    from UserCallData
    where CreationDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
),
cte_totals as
(
    select C1.FromPhone, C1.ToPhone, COUNT(*) as TotalCallCount, SUM(CallDuration) as TotalCallDuration
    from cte C1
    where exists(select * from cte C2 where C1.FromPhone = C2.FromPhone and C1.ToPhone = C2.ToPhone and C2.RN > 1)
    group by C1.FromPhone, C1.ToPhone
)
select C1.*, TotalCallCount, TotalCallDuration
from cte C1
    inner join cte_totals C2 on C1.FromPhone = C2.FromPhone and C1.ToPhone = C2.ToPhone
where C1.RN = 1
```

I wrote query right in here so it can have some mistakes or mistypes, but the main idea might be clear.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! I tried your solution, but I need to group these multiple occurrences into one record by picking first record and count the number of occurrences as TotalCallCount and sum the totalCallDuration. Also the above query is returning only last 3 months data.

Comment: Thanks! this seems to be working. This query is now returning unique records when multiple occurrences are found. Now, how do I bring in other records which doesn't fall into above criteria(where there are no multiple occurrences)?

Comment: I don't understand. You want to see in one result all unique records with counts and sums?

Comment: Try to comment/remove WHERE block in cte_totals.

Comment: Thanks a lot ventik and @Steve Lovell. It's working now. Let me do some testing and get back to you if I have any questions.

Comment: If after testing you're content with one of the offered solutions, do mark that answer as correct (and up-vote it too). You can also up-vote other responses you found helpful but only one can be accepted as "the" answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I've understood the question, but if I have the following may be what you want (or be a useful starting point):

```
SELECT
       ucd.FromPhone,
       min(ucd.CreationDate) as MinCreationDate,
       ucd.ToPhone,
       ucd.MarketName,
       count(*) as TotalCallCount,
       sum(ucd.CallDuration) as TotalCallDuration,
       case
           when min(ucd.WebsiteName) = max(ucd.WebsiteName) then min(ucd.WebsiteName)
           else '* Various'
       end as WebsiteName,
       case
           when min(ucd.ID) = max(ucd.ID) then min(ucd.ID)
           else '* Various'
       end as ID,
       case
           when min(ucd.UserID) = max(ucd.UserID) then min(ucd.UserID)
           else '* Various'
       end as UserID,
       case
           when min(ucd.IsAnswered) = max(ucd.IsAnswered) then min(ucd.IsAnswered)
           else '* Some'
       end as IsAnswered,
       case
           when min(ucd.Source) = max(ucd.Source) then min(ucd.Source)
           else '* Various'
       end as Source
FROM
    dbo.UserCallData ucd
WHERE
    ucd.CreationDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
GROUP BY
    ucd.FromPhone,
    ucd.ToPhone,
    ucd.MarketName
```

Where we are collapsing rows together, if all the rows agree on a given column (so `min(Field) = max(Field)`), I return the `min(Field)` value (which is the same all the others, but avoid problems with needing additional "group by" clauses which would interfere with the other cases). Where they don't all agree, I've returned `"* something"`.

The code assumes that all the columns are text type columns (you haven't said), you may get conversion errors. It also assumes that none of these fields are `null`. You / we can adapt the code if those assumptions aren't correct. If you aren't able to do that for yourself, let me know about issues, I'll be happy to do what I can.

Comment: Based on your comments to ventik, you may want to remove the where clause and add the following in GROUP BY: `group by case when ucd.CreationDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()) then null else ucd.ID end)`. That assumes that ID uniquely identifies the row in the table. If it doesn't you'll need something that does. If there is nothing of that sort available in the table you could use `newid()`.